# Angular 2 Component using External JS libraries

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I just started `Angular2` and while creating a `navbar-component`, I am stuck on how to use the external `JS files`. `CSS` is working fine but i am not able to show `drop-down` and `toggle-button` for mobile-view. So, I guess `javascript` is not working.

I am using this library `mdb` [navbar-materialized-bootsrap](http://mdbootstrap.com/components/navbar/). I need to use these three `JS-files`. 
`mdb.min.js`
`bootsrap.min.js`
`jquery2.2.3.min.js`

Right now,I am just using the `script-tag` to load these files in `index.html`. Please guide me ?

Here are some of my files. ----->

`navbar.component.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector:'navbar', 
  templateUrl: 'navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    'navbar.component.css'
  ],  
})

export class NavbarComponent {
  title='Doctor Application';
}
```

`navbar.component.html`

```
<!-- Collapse button-->
<button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseEx2">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</button>

<div class="container">

    <!--Collapse content-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="collapseEx2">
        <!--Navbar Brand-->
        <a class="navbar-brand">{{title}}</a>
        <!--Links-->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link">Doctors <span class="sr-only"></span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item btn-group">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Cities</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Lahore</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Karachi (Coming Soon)</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item">Islamabad (Coming Soon)</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!--Search form-->
        <form class="form-inline">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
    </div>
    <!--/.Collapse content-->

</div>
```

`index.html`

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="/">
<title>Angular Tour of Heros</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
 <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<!-- 3. Configure your own JS files -->
<script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
 <app>Loading your application</app>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

depending what bundler you are using, if systemJS then you can refer to:
https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

or import them for webpack:
https://angular.io/guide/webpack#entries-and-outputs

Comment: I am using SystemJS. But question is do i need to change my component html ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the Js scripts after the `<app></app>` in your index.html. The code will run sequentialy. So when the js tag is loaded the scripts need the DOM.

Ex:

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="/">
<title>Angular Tour of Heros</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
 <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
</head>
<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
 <app>Loading your application</app>
 <!-- 3. Configure your own JS files -->
<script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="static/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```